# Is there a way to define the user in firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm looking to define the user to send a verification email to, rather than the current user. I've tried to do it by defining the email address of the user in place of the firebase.auth().CurrentUser, but no email gets sent.

I expect it to send the email to the user being defined by email but it does not send

No errors in console or anything

Like I said I tried defining the user by email but it didn't work and I can't find anything to show you how to define a user by email.
My current code is the code snippets on the firebase auth docs for web, with the addition of adding success and failure messages.

```js
function Rever(){
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
  // Email sent.
  alert("User has been sent verification email")
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
  alert("An error has occured. \nContact Support if error persists")
});

}
```

But the `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;` is the problem as I want to send it to a user other than the current user.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Full Code: https://codepen.io/DanS05/pen/qBqMPpX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to send it to a user other than the current user.

That's not possible from the client SDK, as that would be a security hole.  The verification email must be sent to the email address that the user used to sign up.  This prevents their account from being hijacked by another party that simply provides their own email address.

If you want to send an email verification link from another source, that must be driven by your backend using the Firebase Admin SDK as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link).

Comment: What I mean is a staff member can send a verification email to the user, is there a way that my staff can send a verification email to the user?

Comment: It's not possible using the client SDK.  If you want to send a verification email from another source, that needs to be from a backend you control that's using the Firebase Admin SDK.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link